# How can I return corresponding value from Master List by comparing Child List?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 3 columns MasterList, Value and ChildList. Now I want to compare Childlist against Masterlist and get the value from corresponding MasterList.

I have below values in worksheet.

```
MasterList  Value  ChildList ResultValue
A1            2      A1          ?
A2            3      A3          ?
A3            5      B2          ?
B1            1
B2            3
B3            7
```

I want the result like below:

```
MasterList  Value  ChildList ResultValue
A1            2      A1          2
A2            3      A3          5
A3            5      B2          3
B1            1
B2            3
B3            7
```

Please let me know the trick to get the solution.
I have seen vlookup examples to check child list values exist in Master list but did not found how to return values, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are these lists on the same worksheet? Have you tried anything yet? If so, share the formula and we can help you resolve why it isn't working. Does `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, etc. represent cell positions or text in the cells?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) is the answer - `=VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

So for you, in the childlist_value you would put (in `D1`)

```
=Vlookup(C1,!$A$1:$B$100,2,FALSE)
```

Or across sheets, in child_list value (`Sheet2!B1`) -

```
=Vlookup(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$100,2,FALSE)
```

This will take the value on child_list (A1), match it to master_list column A and return the value next to where it is found on master_list (master_list value)

---

Example with your table:

```
         Col A       Col B   Col C    Col D 
Row 1   MasterList  Value  ChildList ResultValue
Row 2    A1            2      A1          =vlookup(C2,$A$2:$B$8,2,FALSE)
Row 3    A2            3      A3          =vlookup(C3,$A$2:$B$8,2,FALSE)
Row 4    A3            5      B2          =vlookup(C4,$A$2:$B$8,2,FALSE)
Row 5    B1            1
Row 6    B2            3
Row 7    B3            7
```